# how to reset the data frame column and in place of missing values append 0's using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have Pandas data frame that looks like this

```
data = {
    'sec': [35,36,38,0,1,2,3,4,5,9],
    'rpm': [40.5,41.6,56,56.8,67,89,90,91,102,123]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i want the output like this in this rpm column from 36,38 the 37 values is missing i want to append 37 value and in rpm place 0 in 37
and 8th index 5 to 9  the 6,7,8 values are missing append missing values and in rpm place 0,0,0

```
data = {
    'sec': [35,36,37,38,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'rpm': [40.5,41.6,0,56,56.8,67,89,90,91,102,0,0,0,123]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
finally my expected output is sec column has to reset like this
data = {
    'sec': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
    'rpm': [40.5,41.6,0,56,56.8,67,89,90,91,102,0,0,0,123]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

finally my expected output is sec column has to reset like this how to do it kindly help me through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['sec'].diff().lt(0).cumsum(),group_keys=False)
.apply(lambda x: x.set_index('sec').reindex(range(x['sec'].min(),x['sec'].max() + 1),fill_value=0))
.reset_index())

df2 = df1.assign(sec = df1.index+1)
```

Output:

```
    sec    rpm
0     1   40.5
1     2   41.6
2     3    0.0
3     4   56.0
4     5   56.8
5     6   67.0
6     7   89.0
7     8   90.0
8     9   91.0
9    10  102.0
10   11    0.0
11   12    0.0
12   13    0.0
13   14  123.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the result your question describes:

```python
df['start'] = df.sec.shift() > df.sec
df.loc[df.start.index[0], 'start'] = True
df['end'] = df.start.shift(-1, fill_value=True)
secFull = list(chain(*map(lambda x, y: list(range(x, y)), df.loc[df.start].sec, df.loc[df.end].sec + 1)))
df = df.set_index('sec').reindex(secFull, fill_value=0).reset_index().drop(columns=['start','end']).assign(sec=list(range(1, len(secFull) + 1)))
```

Output:

```
    sec    rpm
0     1   40.5
1     2   41.6
2     3    0.0
3     4   56.0
4     5   56.8
5     6   67.0
6     7   89.0
7     8   90.0
8     9   91.0
9    10  102.0
10   11    0.0
11   12    0.0
12   13    0.0
13   14  123.0
```

Explanation:

- populate columns `start` and `end` with True marking the bounds of each non-decreasing subsequence within column `sec`
- create a list `secFull` comprising a concatenation of the full integer range for each such subsequence of values in column `sec`
- drop the intermediate columns (`start` and `end`) and use [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to expand the number of rows in the input to make room for the missing `sec` values and fill their corresponding `rpm` values with 0
- replace `sec` with an integer sequence starting at 1.

Comment: this script is worked with my sample which i have posted in my question when i apply to real data it is not allowing duplicates in seconds column when same value is repeating means it is throwing an error rhug123 his code is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas in Python, you may use the **reindex()** and **fillna()** methods to clear the values in the'sec' column of your DataFrame and substitute any missing values with 0. Here is an illustration of how to achieve the needed transformation:

```
   import pandas as pd

data = {
    'sec': [35, 36, 38, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9],
    'rpm': [40.5, 41.6, 56, 56.8, 67, 89, 90, 91, 102, 123]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Find the'sec' column's missing values.
missing_sec = set(range(df['sec'].min(), df['sec'].max() + 1)) - set(df['sec'])

#Make a new DataFrame with appended missing values.
df_missing = pd.DataFrame({'sec': list(missing_sec), 'rpm': 0})

#Add the DataFrame with the missing values to the original one.
df_concat = pd.concat([df, df_missing]).sort_values('sec')

# Reset the DataFrame's index.
df_concat.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Use 0s to fill in any missing values in the 'rpm' column.
df_concat['rpm'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Clear the'sec' column
df_concat['sec'] = range(1, len(df_concat) + 1)

#Print the completed DataFrame.
print(df_concat)

----->Output:
    sec    rpm
0     1   40.5
1     2   41.6
2     3    0.0
3     4   56.0
4     5   56.8
5     6   67.0
6     7   89.0
7     8   90.0
8     9   91.0
9    10  102.0
10   11    0.0
11   12    0.0
12   13    0.0
13   14  123.0
```

Comment: this script not worked for my real data